# How to create TestNG DataProvider out of numbers in scala?

Tags: scala, testng

It sounds really stupid, but i couldn't find the answer neither on StackOverflow or in Google as well. I need to make really simple and easy thing - pass to my TestNG test a Dataprovider that contains two numbers in each set, but i didn't manage to succeed with it . Here's my code:

```
@DataProvider(name = "numbersRandomRange")
def numbersRandomRange() = {
Array(Array(100, 150),
  Array(100.10, 200.01),
  Array(100.10f, 250.10f)
  )
}
```

My test looks like this : 
`

```
  @Test(dataProvider = "numbersRandomRange")
  def testNumbersRandomRange(min: Any, max: Any) {
    def calculate(minValue: Any, maxValue: Any): Any = (minValue, maxValue) match {
      case (min: Int, max: Int) => alpha.number(min, max)
      case (min: Double, max: Double) => alpha.double(min, max)
      case (min: Float, max: Float) => alpha.float(min, max)
    }
    val actualNumber = calculate(min, max)
    logger.info("Checking custom number with  type function. Should return with specific type and below specified value : ")
    expectResult(actualNumber.getClass)(min.getClass)
    assert(util.less(actualNumber, max))
    assert(util.less(min, actualNumber))
  }
`
```

When i try to run it, i get next Error Message :

> > Data Provider public java.lang.Object[] must return either Object[][] or Iterator   [], not class [Ljava.lang.Object;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you annotate the type then it works:

```
  @DataProvider(name = "numbersRandomRange")
  def numbersRandomRange():Array[Array[Any]] = { //Notice that the return type is set
    Array(Array(100, 150),
      Array(100.10, 200.01),
      Array(100.10f, 250.10f)
    )
  }
```

The scala compiler is inferring the return type of `numbersRandomRange` to be `Array[Array[_ >: Float with Double with Int <: AnyVal]]` which is then probably interpreted by java to just be `Object`. By giving the compiler a hint, it makes this work.

Comment: Yes, indeed you are right) I new that there should be an easy solution for this :) Thanks a lot

Comment: I was able to run the tests succesfully, however Intelij IDEA was complaining on type a little bit and this is what made it happy i had to change return type from `:Array[Array[Any]]` to `:Array[Array[_ >: Int with Double with Float <: AnyVal]]`

Comment: @AndrewZakordonetes Intellij will complain about things that are perfectly fine sometimes, the scalaz source code is a great example of this.