# Scala TestNG @DataProvider bug(?) with return type Array[Array[Int]]

Tags: scala, testng, testng-dataprovider

This example ([How to create TestNG DataProvider out of numbers in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109283/how-to-create-testng-dataprovider-out-of-numbers-in-scala)) works for me with my setup.

However, if I change it to below, the test is skipped.

```
@DataProvider(name = "numbersRandomRange")
def numbersRandomRange(): Array[Array[Int]] = { 
  Array(Array[Int](100, 150))
}

@Test(dataProvider = "numbersRandomRange")
def testNumbersRandomRange(min: Int, max: Int) {
  // do something here.
}
```

Not critical at all for me. But can someone shed light on what is going on under the hood with `Array[Array[Int]]` versus `Array[Array[Any]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I do not practice Scala as such , but the difference seems to me to be that [TestNG expects an `Object[][]` as the return type of the `@DataProvider`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders).

> The Data Provider method can return one of the following two types:
>
> - An array of array of objects (`Object[][]`) where the first dimension's size is the number of times the test method will be
>     invoked and the second dimension size contains an array of objects
>     that must be compatible with the parameter types of the test method.
>     This is the cast illustrated by the example above.
> - An `Iterator<Object[]>`. The only difference with `Object[][]` is that an Iterator lets you create your test data lazily. TestNG will invoke
>     the iterator and then the test method with the parameters returned by
>     this iterator one by one. This is particularly useful if you have a
>     lot of parameter sets to pass to the method and you don't want to
>     create all of them upfront.

and when you specify

```
def numbersRandomRange():Array[Array[Any]]
```

it is still interpreted as `Object[][]`, the same should hold for

```
def numbersRandomRange():Array[Array[Object]]
```

---

So, in your case as well you should wrap it as `Object[][]` / `Array[Array[Object]]`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!